# Multiplying modulo 20

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

> For a positive integer $n \ge 2$, define $U(n)= \{k \in \Bbb Z_n $| gcd$(k,n)=1\}$. Then $U(n)$ is a group under multiplication modulo $n$. Find the order of $U(20)$. Is it possible to generate $U(20)$ with a single element? If so, state this element and show it is a generator; if not, find a minimal generating set.

I found that $U(n)=\{1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19\}$ and |$U(20)$|$=8$.

I know that $U(20)$ cannot be generated with a single element. So far I have: $<1,3>$ but I know that I need more elements. Multiplying the elements of $U(20)$ $modulo \ 20$ is tedious. Is there a better way, i.e., a shortcut, to do this?

---

Edit:

I figured out that my subgroup is $<3,11>$, but I just did it by multiplying and subtracting 20 over and over. Is there a better way to do this than multiplying over and over and then subtracting 20 over and over?

Comment: You don't need 1 since $3^4\equiv 1 \pmod{20}$. I believe $<3,11>$ should work however.

Comment: Why do you include $1$ in $\langle 1,3 \rangle$ when in fact $1$ is the neutral element, it doesn't really generate much.

Comment: Ok I edited it to show what I have. But I still would like to know of any better ways to find that <3,11> is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are only required to find a *minimal* generating set and not a set of *minimum size*, you can just start with the whole group and throw out elements until you can't throw out any more.  This shouldn't be too hard.  So to start out
$$
U(n) = \langle 1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19 \rangle
$$
Certainly you can throw out $1$.
Then $3 \cdot 3 = 9, 11 \cdot 3 = 13, 11 \cdot 7 = 17$, so throw out $9, 13, 17$ as well.
$$
U(n) = \langle 3,7,11,19 \rangle
$$
Now $7^2 \cdot 11 = 9 \cdot 11 = 19$, and
$3 \cdot 7 = 1$ i.e. $7 = 3^{-1}$.  So
$$
U(n) = \langle 3, 11 \rangle.
$$

Comment: Thank you! That was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the elements of $U(20)$ and the order of the group. Another way to name the elements (here listed in the same order as you do) is:
$$U(20) = \{ 1,3,7,9,-9,-7,-3,-1 \}$$
and that might be easier to multiply (and should not confuse you when you do *modulo* 20 operations).

Your generating set $\langle 1,3 \rangle$ does not need the element $1$ since $1$ is the neutral element in this group.

To check if the group can be generated by one element, lets first see what $\langle 3 \rangle$ is. $3\cdot 3 = 9$ and $9\cdot 3 = 27 \equiv 7$, and finally $7\cdot 3 = 21 \equiv 1$, so:
$$\langle 3 \rangle = \{ 1,3,9,7 \}$$
a cyclic subgroup of order $4$ whose other generator is $7 \equiv 3^3$:
$$\langle 7 \rangle = \{ 1,7,9,3 \}$$
and of course $\langle 9 \rangle = \{ 1,9 \}$ from this.

With the other elements, we get similarly:
$$\langle -3 \rangle = \{ 1,-3,9,-7 \}$$
and:
$$\langle -7 \rangle = \{ 1,-7,9,-3 \}$$
and $\langle -9 \rangle = \{ 1,-9 \}$ and $\langle -1 \rangle = \{ 1,-1 \}$.

We see that the group is not cyclic.

You will be able to find a set of two generators. Take $3$ as one of them, and try an element not already in $\langle 3 \rangle$ as the other one. Good luck.

Comment: Actually, with my choice of "representatives" between $-10$ and $10$ and the fact $\langle 3\rangle = \{ 1,3,9,7 \}$, it becomes very natural to take $\langle 3,-1 \rangle$ as a generating set.

Answer (score 0):

$|U(n)|=\varphi(n)$ where $\varphi$ is Euler-phi function.
And it is multiplicative,i.e $\varphi(20)=\varphi(4).\varphi(5)=2.4=8$

$U(n)\cong Aut(Z_n)$ thus, $U(20)\cong Aut(Z_{20})\cong (Aut(Z_4)\times Aut(Z_5)\cong Z_2\times Z_4$

Thus,it is not cyclic.

Note that,I used following facts;

$Z_{mn}\cong Z_m\times Z_n$ if and only if $gcd(m,n)=1$ and in that case you can say $Aut(Z_{mn})\cong (Aut(Z_m)\times Aut(Z_n))$

Comment: The OP is not asking whether or not $U(20)$ is cyclic.

Comment: I don't know what any of that means.

Comment: @allie: I showed shortcut to compute $Aut(Z_n)$